# How does logcat log timestamp of a log message?

Tags: android, timestamp, logcat, rewind

I'm trying to measure time ellapsed between two events in android using the timestamp in logcat's message, but unfortunately I noticed a strange thing:the timestamp for the second event is earlier than the first one. It looks like the system time had been reset. How could this happen?

Comment: Instead of relying on the timestamp in logcat, you could use something like `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then log that during the execution of your events.